# Readability of Scientific Python Code (Line Continuations, Variable Names, Imports)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Do Python's stylistic best practices apply to scientific coding?

I am finding it difficult to keep scientific Python code readable.

For example, it is suggested to use meaningful names for variables and to keep the namespace ordered by avoiding `import *`. Thus, e.g. :

```
    import numpy as np
    normbar = np.random.normal(mean, std, np.shape(foo))
```

But these suggestions can lead to some difficult-to-read code, especially given the 79-character line width. For example, I just wrote the following operation:

```
net["weights"][ix1][ix2] += lrate * (CD / nCases - opts["weightcost_pretrain"].dot(net["weights"][ix1][ix2]))
```

I can span the expression across lines:

```
net["weights"][ix1][ix2] += lrate * (CD / nCases - 
     opts["weightcost_pretrain"].dot(net["weights"][ix1][ix2]))
```

but this does not seem much better, and I am not sure how deep to indent the second line. These kinds of line continuations become even trickier when one is double-indented into a nested loop, and there are only 50 characters available on a line.

Should I accept that scientific Python looks clunky, or are there ways to avoid lines like the example above?

Some potential approaches are:

- using shorter variable names
- using shorter dictionary key names
- importing numpy functions directly and assigning them short names
- defining helper functions for combinations of arithmetic operations
- breaking operations into smaller pieces, and placing one on each line

I would appreciate any wisdom on which of these to pursue and which to avoid, as well as suggestions for other remedies.

Comment: PEP 8 now allows for lines up to 99 characters when it improves readability, by the way.

Comment: Your last two approaches are very much in keeping with PEP 8, and pythonic style in general.

Comment: @roippi: [The current version](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) says "Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters… For flowing long blocks… 72 characters." Deep in the middle of the section, it says, "Some teams strongly prefer a longer line length. For  code maintained exclusively or primarily by a team that can reach agreement on this issue, it is okay to increase the nominal line length from 80 to 100 (effectively increasing the maximum length to 99 characters), provided that comments and docstrings are still wrapped at 72 characters."

Comment: @roippi: In other words, it allows 99-character lines, but only in the sense that it allows tabs, allows encodings other than UTF-8 and ASCII, etc.

Comment: @abarnert I see they snuck that one in with http://hg.python.org/peps/rev/bd8c95ad2054

Comment: @roippi: I personally think the whole change was unnecessary, and the argument back and forth and sequence of revisions silly. If you're dealing with "code maintained exclusively or primarily by a team that can reach agreement on this issue", they can already agree to break with PEP 8 on the issue in the first place…

Comment: @abarnert people have their sacred cows, I suppose, none more sacred than PEP8.  At the end of the day it's just a (really good) guideline.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, folks, +1. I will reorganize along the lines suggested and will then `timeit` to see if there is any performance effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - defining helper functions for combinations of arithmetic operations
> - breaking operations into smaller pieces, and placing one on each line

These are both good ideas—in keeping with the intent behind PEP 8, and with Pythonic style in general. In fact, whenever someone suggests modifying PEP 8 to give more information about long lines, half the responses are usually "If you're going over the line limit, you're probably doing too much in one expression".

And, more generally, factoring out code and giving sensible names to sensible operations are always a good idea.

Of course without knowing exactly what all these things represent, I can only guess at how to split them up, but I think something like this would be pretty readable and meaningful:

```
cost = opts["weightcost_pretrain"].dot(net["weights"][ix1][ix2])
weight = lrate * (CD / nCases - cost)
net["weights"][ix1][ix2] += weight
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the style guide always applies- I use Python daily for scientific work and find that I'm able to read my code more easily and come back to it months later with little effort if I've split up long lines into logical components and sensible variable names, or used a function.

I'd do something more like this:

```
weights = net["weights"][ix1][ix2]
opts_arr = opts["weightcost_pretrain"]
weights += lrate * (CD / nCases - opts_arr.dot(weights))
```

Another way of saying that Python is "concise" is that Python is syntactically dense, and I find it harder to read and understand a long line of Python than a long line of Java (especially when using high-level functions from 3rd party libraries that hide low-level logic, like NumPy).

Comment: +1. I like the point about Python being syntactically dense. Of course partisans of Java or Smalltalk will tell you that this is why operator overloading is a bad idea—but really, all it means is that the cost of excessively-long lines are higher, and as long as you avoid excessively-long lines, Python is very readable. (Like mathematical notation compared to English-language description—it's possible to write an equation so long it can't be processed, but it's easy to avoid, and so long as you do, math is much easier to read.)